Can't request `always` location authorization
I'm trying to request always access to location updates. According to Apple's documentation, I need to add the key NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription to my info.plist and call requestAlwaysAuthorization() on my CLLocationManager.
However, this simply don't work. There's no authorization request popups nor any error messages:
ContentView()
    .onAppear {
        CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }


It DOES work when I change the info.plist key to NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and call requestWhenInUseAuthorization() instead.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I also tried adding "Location updates" capabilities:


You have to call when in use first and then always

You need to watch a WWDC video about how to use location requests.

huh? Am I the only one that's confused here? It would be awesome if I happened to stubble upon the right WWDC video to watch here but I don't think it's far fetched to say that most people's intuition for something like this would be to read the documentations first. And when I read it it mentioned nothing about requesting "when-in-use" first when that's clearly a prerequisite. Documentations like this is not helpful and would be roasted for any of the OSS frameworks out there. Sry for the rant, but Apple is not making it easy for new developers.

And trust me, the links I provided are not the only documentations I read. None of the Apple articles I looked through mentioned anything about this.

The first link leads you to the detailed information

The first link does not. Can you point to me where in that link it says "request when-in-use" first?

Your link has a “for more information link” once in there there is a bold box that says “if you have when in use you can request always”

Are you referring to the note that says "If your app requests and receives When In Use authorization, you can make a separate request for Always authorization later?"

I don't think anyone will look at sentence and interpret it as a "When-in-use is a prerequisite." This has been answered by @yo1995 below.

I think Apple's documentation needs improvement here, as you need to dig through several pages to find the right way to do it. But it might be hard to follow on purpose.

First, there is this article Choosing the Location Services Authorization to Request. It basically says you can request a Always authorization by itself, so you are correct on that regard.
How to request the Always authorization then? It leads to this API page: requestAlwaysAuthorization. In this page, it reads


You must call this or the requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method before your app can receive location information. To call this method, you must have both NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in your app’s Info.plist file.


which can be counterintuitive - "if I'm only requesting Always, why need 2 keys in the plist?!"


Finally, there is the difference between macOS and iOS. If your app is multi-platform, you'll learn the hard way how much hassle it takes to get through App Store Connect. But that is a story for another time.

Think of it this way - the "When In Use" authorization is the base case for all authorization. You must present that alert as the first step for location permissions.
Furthermore, even if you have requested and got granted the "Always" permission, iOS will still prompt the user at random future times with the "Change to Only While Using" alert.
So you get the idea… Apple just doesn't want you to use "Always".
